# A good alternative to the Swagger's externalValue option

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I would like to use the `externalValue` of OpenAPI like it's shown in the [docs](https://swagger.io/specification/). But it looks like the swagger-UI is currently does not support `externalValue` ([link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433)). Was it ever supported by the Swagger-UI? If so, is it possible to go to some previous version and use it? I have tried to go throughout the release notes and find if it was ever released but could not find it. If it's not supported by Swagger-UI, then why it's described in details in the docs? I'm a bit confused how the OpenAPI/Swagger system works.

If there is no previous version of Swagger-UI which I can use for `externalValue`, what would be the best option to the current situation? it's a bit difficult to create the examples manually (too big).